# How do I build 32-bit libc++ with 64-bit clang v8 on 64-bit Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: c++, linux, clang, llvm

Using a `Dockerfile`, I'm attempting to build Clang version v8 along with its dependencies on Ubuntu 18.04. The reason I'm going through all this trouble is because I can't find a 32-bit version of the LLVM libraries. Even the LLVM packages themselves have only 64-bit variants of everything. Because of this, I'm not able to build my 32-bit applications using the LLVM toolchain at version 8. Using version 8 of LLVM is mandatory for reasons I won't go into here.

So far, here is what I have:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS build

ARG NUM_PARALLEL=8

RUN true \
    && dpkg --add-architecture i386 \
    && apt-get -qq update \
    && apt-get -qq install \
        software-properties-common \
        build-essential \
        gcc-multilib \
        g++-multilib \
        git \
        wget \
        autoconf \
        pkg-config \
        m4 \
        python-dev:i386 \
        libcurl4-gnutls-dev:i386 \
        libncurses-dev:i386 \
        uuid-dev:i386 \
        libx11-dev:i386 \
        libxext-dev:i386 \
        libtinfo-dev:i386 \
        libedit-dev:i386 \
        swig \
        libedit-dev
        python-dev

ENV CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL=$NUM_PARALLEL

# Ninja
RUN true \
    && git clone --depth 1 --branch v1.8.2 https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja.git \
    && cd ninja \
    && ./configure.py --bootstrap \
    && cp ninja /usr/local/bin

# CMake
RUN true \
    && git clone --depth 1 --branch v3.13.4 https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake.git \
    && cd cmake \
    && ./bootstrap --parallel=$NUM_PARALLEL \
    && make -j$NUM_PARALLEL install

# Clang (See: https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html)
RUN true \
    && git clone --depth 1 --branch llvmorg-8.0.0 https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git \
    && cd llvm-project \
    && cmake -G Ninja -B build -S llvm \
        -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
        -D LLVM_BUILD_32_BITS:BOOL=ON \
        -D LLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=all \
        -D LLVM_BUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF \
        -D LLVM_BUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF \
        -D LLVM_INCLUDE_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF \
        -D LLVM_INCLUDE_TESTS:BOOL=OFF \
        -D LLVM_INCLUDE_BENCHMARKS:BOOL=OFF \
    && cmake --build build -j $NUM_PARALLEL --target install
```

I get through compiling a little over 5200 translation units, which takes over an hour, only for it to fail:

```
[5232/6435] Linking CXX shared library lib/readline.so
FAILED: lib/readline.so
: && /usr/bin/c++ -fPIC -fPIC -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -m32 -Werror=date-time -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-missing-field-initializers -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-noexcept-type -Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-color -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-deprecated-register -Wno-vla-extension -Wno-macro-redefined -O3 -DNDEBUG  -Wl,-z,defs -Wl,-z,nodelete -m32 -shared -Wl,-soname,readline.so -o lib/readline.so tools/lldb/scripts/Python/modules/readline/CMakeFiles/readline.dir/readline.cpp.o  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libedit.so && :
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I followed the [getting started](https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) page to understand how to build LLVM so far, but I must be missing something. They don't exactly go into 32-bit compilation in their examples. Can someone help me get this building? Or at least (and probably better), point me to a version of Clang v8 that has 32-bit LLVM libraries bundled with it?

Comment: Are you trying to build libc++ or the whole LLVM/Clang toolchain? Also, why do you assume that x64 Clang compiler can't target x86 arch? What did you do with previous version of LLVM/Clang?

Comment: I never said the x64 compiler can't target x86. What I'm saying is that the 32-bit LLVM libraries are not available, so using `-m32` causes linker failures due to `libc++` missing (since it's not available for the i386 architecture).

Comment: clang by default uses system libstdc++, but anyway, if you only want libc++, why are you building the whole LLVM (with ninja and cmake to boot)? Have you read https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/BuildingLibcxx.html ?

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu already, can't you `dpkg --add-architecture i386` and then `apt-get install libc++1:i386` ? (see [Debian multiarchitecture](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO#Installing_Android_SDK_compat_libraries))

Comment: @Botje [the libc++1 package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/libc++1) is for Clang v7, not v8, and also requires v18.10 of ubuntu (I'm on 18.04 and that cannot change).

Comment: @DanM. Yep I saw that link, but mostly they just point to the same getting started page I linked earlier.

Comment: @void.pointer it shows how to build libc++ separately from llvm. You don't need to waste hours recompiling llvm/clang if you only need to build libc.

Comment: @DanM. I feel like that documentation might be outdated. I'm not able to get it working. I think the way it's structured requires that you generate projects through the `llvm` subdirectory first. It has all the common CMake logic. Without that, none of the other projects build successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are linking against the wrong Python: `usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so`.

You may want to for it and add it to the CMake commands:

```
-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=PATH_TO_PYTHON-DEV:i686
```

You may also need to set `PYTHON_LIBRARY` and `PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR` to make sure that the i386 versions are used.